# Angular.js, $resource, how to manage multiple asynchronous requests

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I am implementing a "copy on write" CRUD system meaning i never overwrite a database entry but mark as inactive and write a new record. When editing an existing record this means i write to the old record deactivating then create a new record.  My controller code is below:

```
$scope.save = function() {

  if(!$scope.newDevice){
    var editDevice = $scope.device;
    $scope.delete(editDevice);
    $scope.device = {name: editDevice.name, type: editDevice.type, hash: editDevice.hash};
  }

  var newDevice = new DeviceService($scope.device);
  newDevice = newDevice.$save(function(newDevice, putResponseHeaders) {
    DeviceService.query({active : true}, function(devices){
      $scope.devices = devices;
    });
  });  
};
```

When i call to get the list of active devices with DeviceService.query({active : true} I still get the old record as active since it executes and returns before the delete method has been processed and returned.

I think i should be using promise maybe.  How do i write this code to be better and work?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you want to use promises. You have two options:

1. Use the success/failure callbacks that all $resource methods supply. Note you're using this when you call $save. You could do the same when you call $delete on the resource, so that your remaining code only executes when the $delete() succeeds. These callbacks are automatically invoked when the $resource's built-in promise is resolved or rejected.
2. Make your `$scope.delete()` function return a promise. It sounds like this might be better, because you do not always want to make the delete request.

The code for #2 might look like this:

```
// this function use the '$q' service, which you need to inject
// in your controller
$scope.delete = function(item) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  item.$delete({},
    function(response) {
      // the delete succeeded, resolve the promise
      deferred.resolve(response);
    },
    function(error) {
      // failed, reject the promise
      deferred.reject(error);
    }
  );
  return deferred.promise;
}

$scope.save = function() {

  if(!$scope.newDevice){
    var editDevice = $scope.device;
    $scope.delete(editDevice).then(function(response) {
       $scope.device = {name: editDevice.name, type: editDevice.type, hash: editDevice.hash};
       // now trigger the code to save the new device (or whatever)
       $scope.doTheActualSave();
    },
    function(error) { });

  } else {
    // there was nothing to delete, just trigger the code to save
    $scope.doTheActualSave();
  } 
};

$scope.doTheActualSave = function() {
  var newDevice = new DeviceService($scope.device);
  newDevice = newDevice.$save(function(newDevice, putResponseHeaders) {
    DeviceService.query({active : true}, function(devices){
      $scope.devices = devices;
    });
  }); 
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I knew promise was valuable, was not sure how to do.  very much appreciated